# Picture not swapping

Tags: javascript, selector

I am trying to select two images using Javascript  Query Selector and swap them with a click. However if select the image themselves with their Ids the console log shows a null value and if i do it through a list it does  not work. At first I thought  maybe because the system cannot find the path so i made a variable for both images and tried relative as well as normal paths but nothing is working .
Here is my code:

```
 <ul>
        <li class="list"><img src="pepsi001.png" alt=""></li>
        <li class="list2"><img src="pepsi002.png" alt=""></li>
    </ul>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var image = document.querySelector('.list')
var image2 = document.querySelector('.list2')

  image2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    image.src = "F:\Desktop\web development\JS\query selector\pepsi002.png"

})
```

Comment: only on second img click they will swap?

Comment: Yes I  when I click on image 2, I want image one to become image 2 as well

Answer (score 0):

you use class in wrong element

```
    <ul>
      <li><img src="demo.png" alt="" class="list" /></li>
      <li><img src="demo2.png" alt="" class="list2" /></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
      const image = document.querySelector(".list");
      const image2 = document.querySelector(".list2");
      image2.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const prev = image.src;
        image.src = image2.src;
        image2.src = prev;
      });
    </script>
```